# Scan dir, create php array with new keys starting from 1 and rising with each file found (all my keys are [1])

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to scan a directory then put the files it finds into an array which I can then later call in a for each loop but not getting the results I desire with my current code...

```
<?php

$files = scandir('audio');
foreach ($files as $file) {

$arr = array($file);
$iOne = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), array_values($arr));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($iOne);
echo "</pre>";

}

?>
```

produces..

```
Array
(
    [1] => .
)

Array
(
    [1] => ..
)

Array
(
    [1] => audio1.mp3
)

Array
(
    [1] => audio2.mp3
)

Array
(
    [1] => audio3.mp3
)

Array
(
    [1] => audio4.mp3
)
```

When I wanted

```
Array
(
    [1] => audio1.mp3
    [2] => audio2.mp3
    [3] => audio3.mp3
    [4] => audio4.mp3
)
```

Note I also removed `.` & `..` from the second output.

I'm very new to PHP and arrays and as such despite me reading several similar questions it is my lack of understanding that is stopping me achieve my desired results. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've tried the answer suggested by Nick

```
<?php
$files = scandir('audio');
$files = array_slice($files, 2);
$files = array_combine(range(1, count($files)), $files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($file);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

but this displays..

```
audio1.mp3
audio2.mp3
audio3.mp3
audio4.mp3
```

not

```
 Array
    (
        [1] => audio1.mp3
        [2] => audio2.mp3
        [3] => audio3.mp3
        [4] => audio4.mp3
    )
```

Comment: Why do you want the keys to start at 1?

Comment: I would like to use these values for a later function that can't start with 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$files` is already an array; all you need to do is remove the `.` and `..` entries from it. They will be the first two entries assuming your filenames all start with letters. Then you can re-index if you want to:

```
$files = scandir('audio');
$files = array_slice($files, 2);
$files = array_combine(range(1, count($files)), $files);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Please check my edit at the bottom of my OP, Thanks.

Comment: @GlenKeybit just `print_r($files);`, you don't need the `foreach` loop

Comment: If I print_r($files); I do get the array I want but its repeated 4 times?

Comment: You don't need the `foreach` loop. See my edited code.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I worked out I didn't need the for each loop just as you replied. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest solution is the `array_values` function

```php
$files = scandir('audio');
$files = array_values($files);
```

**Documentation:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php